# Given a hash code, check if a Set contains an object

Tags: java, search, set, iteration

I have overriden `equals` and `hashCode` for a custom object `Foo`. Now, I have the hash code of an object and would like to check if the object is contained in the `Set<Foo> fooSet`. Is there a more efficient way to search for it other than

```
for(Foo o : fooSet) {
       if(o.hashCode == inputCode) {
          return true;
       }
 }
```

Comment: that's right. I am storing the hashCode in a basic datatype such as `int` and would like to later check if the corresponding object exists in a `Set`.

Comment: Don't do that - it's fundamentally a bad idea in almost all cases.

Comment: Deleted my comment because Jon's answer made me realize it wasn't really helpful... But I have to ask: *Why*?

Comment: Because I can only store a string or an int. That is my restriction. And I should map this value to an object.

Comment: That's a rather... interesting... restriction. If you could *only* pick a `String` or `int`, one thing you could try to do is create a one-to-one mapping between a `Foo` and `String`, so that all the info that you use for `equals()` makes it into the `String`, if that makes sense. It's really not a good design decision, though, and there almost certainly is a better solution...

Comment: Basically, ensure that the underlying method for equals and hashCode do not cause collisions. Is that correct? So to go back to my question, I just have to iterate through all the objects until I find a matching one. There is no efficient binary search or so?

Comment: What is the type of the actual value here? You usually can't avoid hash collisions unless there are really only 2^32 possible values. I think you need to take a step back and redesign.

Comment: The actual object is a combination of string and integer values. The redesign would enable me to store the object and I guess for now I shall go ahead with the current design. 2^32 is very very large  for my use case actually.

Comment: @user592748 Something like that -- You'll essentially need to add an additional clause to the `hashCode()` contract, so that equal `hashCode()` means `equals()` will return true. You'll need to make sure to document this *extremely* thoroughly -- it's not something most developers would (and should!) rely on. No binary search because `HashMap`s are not ordered. As Jon says, you should probably redesign so this isn't necessary, as using `contains()` is *so* much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically *can't* determine it reliably based on a hash code. You can check that a value definitely *isn't* in the set, but even if you find a matching hash code that doesn't mean that the value *is* in the set. This is rarely useful, which is why there's nothing which exposes the functionality within `Set`. I don't know of any faster way of achieving this half-result. (Note that if you've just got a `Set` rather than a `HashSet`, there may well be nothing in the internal data structures which has recorded hash codes anyway...)

If you *really* only care about the presence of a hash code, just store a `Set<Integer>` instead of the full set. But it's not terribly useful to do so, usually.

Comment: If I use a HashSet, which I do, is there any method exposed to do so readily? Also, when you say even if there is a matching hash code, it does not necessarily mean it is a match, then does it not also apply to matching 2 objects with equals or contains since the underlying method is the same?

Comment: @user592748: No, I don't think there's anything in HashSet to do this either, because it's almost never useful. The point is that a HashSet narrows down the candidates quickly using the hash code, then uses equals to check with certainty.

Answer (score -1):

Checking hash code of 2 objects doesn't guarantee that the objects are equals which means the object may not be in the Set even though hash codes of both objects are equal.

Also I didn't understand your purpose of having faster way of doing. If you mean you want to avoid looping and looking for an alternate then use the contains() method of the Set like below:

```
fooSet.contains(inputObject);
```

Comment: `contains()` requires an object input. OP only has the result of `hashCode()`.

Comment: Just with hashcode you wont be able to determine whether two objects are equal or not. To be specific to check whether an object exists in the Set equals is the method to check. But did you write hash code in such way that if 2 hashcode are equal then their objects are equal?

Comment: I'm not OP :P But the second part of your answer still isn't quite right; as is, there *isn't* a faster way of looking given what info OP has. `contains()` doesn't work in this case.